# Adobe's air/Flash for developing Android apps?

Tags: android, air-android

I recently found out that adobe's flash can also be used to develop android application, so I wanted to ask if there are any significant downsides or limitations to it, comparing with java? Such as am I able to access all the phone features, like GPS location, camera, etc. , when developing in Flash?

Thanks!

Comment: GPS yes, Camera no. Even though Android and iOS support apps built in flash they lag very much. A flash app that runs at 20-40 fps on your desktop/laptop will run in 1-5 fps on your device.

Comment: @Fredrik, Camera also YES. There are quite some application on the Market using AIR and Cameras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/mobile-development-flash-platform.html) on Adobe web site:

- Camera and microphone
- Accelerometer
- GPS
- StageWebView
- Multitouch and gestures
- Screen orientation / full-screen
- Phone/SMS/e-mail/browser/Android Market integration
- Session cache support restore app state
- Hardware buttons
- Local databases SQLite
- Android permissions for Internet, SD card, GPS, camera, and so on

Are available to Air.

Considering performance, although I never have access to any benchmark results, I would bet (OK, I am a gambler here) it is a little bit slower (comparing per operation) with Adobe Air vs Java, although both of them are running on top of VMs.

Major Downsides on Air:

1. Client required to install Adobe Air platform on their Machine
2. (more importantly) your application would hardly looks like other application on Android... since you don't have access to native Android's UI widgets